# jtable checkbox checked row remove from table when click button?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

The below code is part of my button action.Jtable contain last row is checkbox.
When i click save button the selected row must delete from table row...!!!'

**Action performed code**

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if(e.getSource()==btnSave){
    for (int i = 0; i < retunTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
        Boolean chked = Boolean.valueOf(retunTable.getValueAt(i, 4)
                .toString());
        String dataCol1 = retunTable.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
        if (chked) {


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, dataCol1);
            colVaules.add(dataCol1);
            returnBook();
            DefaultTableModel dm=(DefaultTableModel) retunTable.getModel();


        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: where do you actually try and remove the row? Have you tried `dm.removeRow(i)`? And what's with all the `!!!`?

Comment: no but i need to know check button checked row number to try that code

Comment: _"no but i need to know check button checked row number to try that code"_ isn't that what to loop is for, to loop through the rows, `i` being the row?

Comment: See my answer below if you haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. You're class should already have overridden the `getColumnClass()` of the model, so no need for the `toString()` thing your trying to do. The `getValueAt()` should return a cast-able `Boolean` object. Also if you are going to loop and remove rows dynamically in the loop, you need to take into account that the model's row count will decrease with each removal of a row, so will also need to `i--` every time a row is removed. See example below.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestCheckedTable {

    public TestCheckedTable() {
        String[] cols = {"col 1", "col 2", "col 3"};
        Object[][] data = new Object[15][];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = new Object[]{"Hello", "World", false};
        }

        final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
                return col == 2 ? Boolean.class : String.class;
            }
        };
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        JButton button = new JButton("Delete Checked Rows");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    Boolean checked = (Boolean) model.getValueAt(i, 2);
                    if (checked) {
                        model.removeRow(i);
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestCheckedTable();
            }

        });
    }
}
```